# Pushing to properties in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I spent a lot of time trying to catch a bug in my app. Eventually I set apart this piece of code which behavior seems very strange to me.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    myProperty: []
});

var one = new Model();
var two = new Model();
one.myProperty.push(1);
console.log(two.myProperty); //1!!
```

What's the reason behind it? Why it acts so? How to avoid this type of bugs in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance in JavaScript is prototypical - objects can refer directly to properties higher up in the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

In your example, `one` and `two` both share a common prototype, and do not provide their own values for `myProperty` so they both refer directly to `Model.protoype.myProperty`.

You should create new `myProperty` array for each model you instantiate. `Model.initialize` is the idiomatic place for this kind of initialisation - overriding `constructor` is unnecessarily complex.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.myProperty = [];
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could make `myProperty` as an attribute of the model:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
      return {
        myProperty: []
      }
    }
});
```

It is important to note that `defaults` is a function - if you were to use a simple object you would encounter the same shared reference issue.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of initializing myProperty in initialize (sorry for tautology :D), but it seemed strange to me that initializing it in another way leads to different results. At least it's semantically not obvious... But it's javascipt problem, not Backbone, I guess.

Comment: Exactly - the key point is that is a JavaScript, not a Backbone thing. It's not inherently a problem, in fact it's completely necessary for a prototype system - without it, your Model instances could not share methods or common properties without creating a lot of duplicate objects. It does cause this type of bug very often though!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> constructor / initialize new Model([attributes], [options])
>
> When creating an instance of a model, you can pass in the initial values of the attributes, which will be set on the model. If you define an initialize function, it will be invoked when the model is created.
>
> In rare cases, if you're looking to get fancy, you may want to override constructor, which allows you to replace the actual constructor function for your model.

So, following the documentation, you'd want to do something like this to get your case running:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.myProperty = [];
    }
});
```

source: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend

Comment: Why would you override `constructor` to provide the same functionality of `initialize`?

Comment: @Jivings Because you're copy-pasting from the documentation page. Edited `initialize` into post

Answer (score 1):

Actually its because `myProperty` is an array, and as you know arrays will be stored by reference. Just to test consider the following code:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
 myProperty: [],
 messege: ''
});

var one = new Model();
var two = new Model();

one.messege = 'One!';
two.messege = 'Two!';

console.log(one.messege ); // 'One!'
console.log(two.messege ); // 'Two!'
```

An alternative around this could be:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    this.myProperty = [];
    Backbone.Model.apply(this);
  }
});

var one = new Model();
one.myProperty.push(1);

var two = new Model();
console.log(two.myProperty); // []
```

Comment: It's important to point out that the reason `one` and `two` share a reference is prototypical inheritance - the child objects share a reference to a parent property.

Comment: Also, Backbone provides `Model.initialize` for this kind of initialisation - overriding `constructor` is overkill. The Backbone docs say "In rare cases, if you're looking to get fancy, you may want to override constructor...". This isn't a rare case - it's the exact common use case that `initialize` is intended for.

Comment: @joews That's right, `initialize` is a better choice in this case.

Comment: But I will keep my answer unchanged to search more about `constructor` in backbone models.